# Database Option for Client Side Application without administrative right

Tags: javascript, database

My company is quite conservative and behind in technology. We only upgraded from 2003 MS Office Suite *a few months ago*(!!!!). I am trying to improve the work flow and build some client-side application, to replace the work that is done by massive copy and pasting Excel Worksheet. (It is well over 50MB and a lot of information are duplicated).

My current situation:

- Unable to install anything on the computer (no administrative right)
- Team members all has 2013 MS Office, with standard IE 11
- Our team has access to share drive
- Need to support 5-10 person reading and writing at the same time
- The application involves: Entering the case number, lookup the member's information by SSN, or Date of Birth, updating information as needed. Entering the client's inquires and adding the case note. Allow them to download their report (delimited text file?)

I am not sure what kind of options I have? I tried to google and search on the site. I have only some very vague idea... SQLite with Javascript (IE 11)? or CouchDB? or [IndexedDB](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#introduction)?

I am looking for a standalone self contained "Database" that can allow me to place in on the company's shared network drive, and I can build a client side (web application that interact with the Database).

Comment: Well, good luck! Sorry, but I would almost suggest notepad if you may not install anything. I would try to find maybe an old machine and install a basic LAMP (Linux Apache MySQL Php) and build from there. I believe most work is to show your boss that it is time to innovate, and best way is to come up with a working example

Comment: I see I see... let me do more thinking. Thanks!